# Morita-invariance of Hochschild (co)homology.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

Ok, I’m reading the paper *[Homology and cohomology of associative algebras. A concise introduction to cyclic homology](http://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/11/98/91/PDF/Kassel-ICTPnotes2004.pdf)* by Christian Kassel, and on page 19 he says that Hochschild homology is Morita-invariant, by which he means that if $R$ and $S$ are two Morita equivalent rings then
$$
  H_*(R,M) \cong H_*(S, Q \otimes_R M \otimes_R P)
$$
(here $H_*$ denotes Hochshild homology).
He then shows how
$$
  H_*(M,M) \cong H_*(S,S) \,,
$$
and states that

> Hochschild cohomology groups are Morita-invariant in a similar way.

I wanted to find a proof or reference for this? Just wanted to be completely sure about this and avoid any confusion, in what similar way are Hochschild cohomology groups Morita-invariant? Please be nice lol.

Comment: All is at pag. 19: the functors $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ preserve projective resolutions (of bimodules) and the Hochschild (co)homology is defined as a derived functor. Remember that derived functors do not depend on the choice of resolution, hence the isomorphisms

Comment: Check out paragraph 1.5.6 in Loday's "Cyclic Homology".

Comment: The proof for homology can be found in Weibel, chapter 9

Comment: Both references are great books

Comment: Lol that was staring me right in the face the whole time, I was actually going by Weibel's proof and was curious about the cohomology case and used Kassel as a reference, thank you all for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Why don't you write down an answer by your own? It would be a nice exercise, and this post would be "completed" :-)

Comment: A fun partial answer to this is, if your associative algebra is of finite hochschild cohomological dimension, then you can conclude the result by van den bergh duality

Comment: A concise way to think about it is that a Morita equivalence induces in particular a derived equivalence, and that Hochschild (co)homology is just computing a tensor product or hom-set in this derived category, i.e. a more general statement says that derived Morita equivalent (Rickard's work) algebras have isomorphic Hochschild (co)homology